# drop column or rename column with foreign MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Added just a column with a foreign key.
Realized that I had forgot a "t".

Drop'd the foreign key, but still get the fault-- Error on rename of '.... when i try to change or drop the column.

Don't have any more idea's....

Any idea's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the database in phpMyAdmin, select the SQL option from the top bar.

In there type `ALTER Table [tablename] change [old column name] [new column name] [data type (eg varchar)] ([field length])`

Something like `ALTER Table Users change firstname first_name text (25) ;`

Hopefully that's what you where asking

Joe

Comment: That is the command im trying to execute, but I only get the error as described in the question.

Comment: Well that very strange then! All i can suggest is that you export that table as an SQL file. Delete the whole table. Open the SQLFile in Note pad or thing similar and then change the table name in there. Then import that SQL file and create the table again.